# How do I give an answer?

Tags: discussion

On this website I'd like to answer people's requests but I'm not sure how xD.. Is there like an answer button or something or am I just blind.. Probably both honestly ^-^
Basically just how do I ask questions on arcade?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest reading through the [Tour] page, there's a lot of information about how we handle Q&A here and getting yourself familiar with the site. There is also a [Help] and a [Answer] page that will assist you too.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 1):

While looking at any question, scroll down and you will see a text box labeled "Your Answer."  From here, you can fill in the text box with your answer, and press the "Post Your Answer" button once you are finished.

The help pages don't have anywhere that I was able to find that actually discuses how to *actually* answer a question, but I encourage you to take a look at our rules [about answering questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/answering) and the guidelines for answering posts.

If a post is protected, you will need a minimum of 10 reputation to post an answer to it.  This is a mechanism in place to prevent spam answers or "thank you" answers on posts. There are also posts that can be locked by site moderators, which means that **nobody** can post any new answers, vote on the post, or even leave a comment.  Very few posts are locked, so the chances that you'll come across one are slim.

Comment: The question is likely protected and requires OP to have 10 rep to answer